# Gradle cannot resolve androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I'm currently working on a school project and pulled the code from here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/connections/rockpaperscissors. I'm using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2018.3. (Well, it's basically an Android Studio as well)

I worked on that project for several days and everything works **fine** until today i found this Gradle error:

```
Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01
Show in File


Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
```

Here's my project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha06'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's my module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "{my school project Id}"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
}
```

What **i have done** to solve this:

1. Invalidate/Restart IntelliJ
2. Rebuild/Clean project
3. Checked Google Maven Repository for possible typos on package names
4. Restarted my computer
5. Reinstalled Google Play Services

What makes me more frustrated is the fact that everything is fine yesterday! So, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to change dependencies on build.gradle to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by doing this. I hope it helps you too

1- Add the following "repositories" in your build.gradle :

```
google()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
maven { url 'https://github.com/akapelrud/Rotary-Seekbar/raw/master/RotaryKnob/snapshots' }
```

2- Add the following "proxy" in your gradle.properties :

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8118

systemProp.https.proxyHost=fodev.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8118
```

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this issue by doing following steps:

1. Go to any java file.
2. Observe which import can not be resolved. In my case, it was support library. For example, `androidx.appcompat.....`.
3. Go to app level gradle file.
4. Update the relevant dependencies to latest release. For instance, I have changed `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'`  to `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'`.
5. Sync Now.